# Why Doesn't my Named Anchor Work?

Tags: html, anchor

It's been a LONG time since I've used a named anchor. I've never had trouble before. I see a lot has changed in the interim. Here's some sample code that I'm trying to get to work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Named Anchor</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h2 style="text-align: center;">Named Anchor</h2>
  <p>Part 1 - The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.</p>
  <!-- The immediately preceeding line repeats 31 times. -->
  <p id="p2">Part 2 - The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.</p>
  <p>Part 2 - The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.</p>      
  <!-- The immediately preceeding line repeats 30 times. -->
 </body>
</html>
```

If the above code is contained in a file named test1.html, I would expect that a URL that looks like the following would display the page beginning with the "part 2" lines:

```
http://example.com/test1.html#p2
```

It doesn't. The whole page is displayed beginning at the top. Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: Anchors are `<a>` tags, not `<p>` (those are paragraphs).

Comment: What in the world is a "named anchor"?

Comment: The above example works as expected; the page jumps down to the `#p2` ID. Keep in mind that if you have multiple elements with the same ID on your page, then the anchors won't work, which could be the cause of your problem. More documentation on anchors can be found [**here**](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#h-12.2.3).

Comment: Your code works exactly as described: https://jsfiddle.net/1ov6sthm/

Comment: It doesn't work for me.  I only have one <p> element that has an id. That's why I have the <p> tag following the one that has the id and before the comment.  My actual code is at http://www.djolley.net/test/namedAnchor.html.  I'm using the chrome browser.  --  I knew that I was dating myself with the "named anchor".  That used to be the only way to do this.  It's an anchor tag with a name. You'll find it in the history books. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks.  You guys are right.  It started working for me.  I'm suspecting that it was a caching issue, although I tried clearing my cache.  I really don't know what the problem was; but, it seems to have disappeared.  Thanks for the help.